# SOAP web service is not working only for IOS device, it is working in soap ui and Android devices

Tags: php, ios, linux, web-services

We changed PHP version to 5.4.45 from 5.4.25 and installed MS SQL Driver on Server. Before server change, everything was working but after server change, I am facing web service issue. Our authentication Soap web service(written in Zend framework1) is not working only for IOS Devices. It is working for Android and from soap UI even we tried multiple times from Android and SOAP UI. It works every time.

if we uninstall the app in IOS device and reinstall then for the first time authentication web service works fine but if we call this service again then we are getting HTML data inside the response body which is not the actual response.

Same input request we are sending from ios and Android device.

Please suggest...

Comment: what was the resolution. Similar issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was because of "debug mode". It was set to "true" in development environment. Now I set it to "false" and found web service is working for Android, IOS and from soap UI.